# Dark matter and standard model of cosmology: how does it enter into the equation?

Tags: cosmology, dark-matter, cosmic-microwave-background

I am a physics student and don't know very much about dark matter nor cosmology. But today I went to a talk in which the speaker showed us this image (or a very similar one):

[image]

showing how the predictions of the standard model of cosmology having to do with background radiation vary when the ratio of dark matter is modified. I don't know what is the meaning of that plot but it seem that varying the ratio of dark mater produces a very important change in it.

My question is: how is that something that does not interact with electromagnetic radiation (as dark matter) has such a drastic effect in CMB?